# Why a class that implements an interface can't use a static method of that interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface, static, default

Consider a class `A` that implements an interface `B` which has a `static` method `info()`. Why is not possible to do `A.info()`? If it was a default method, it would be possible to do `A.info()` and I don't understand why there is a difference: they are two kinds of methods that are not `abstract` but are already defined in the `interface`, the difference should be only the fact one is `static` and the other is not.

Comment: Static methods belong to the class and are not inheritable. Therefore there is not such thing a `A.info()`, the static method `info()`, from your example, belongs to the class `B` and should be called by doing `B.info()` to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Can you please provide example code in addition to the explanation. Read [mcve] for tips on providing a good code example.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind: there is no polymorphism for static methods.

So, when you have two *classes* A and B - yes, then you can call A.info(). But that is a discouraged practice - as you are still calling the static method from B.

Thus *guessing*: the people behind the Java language simply want to prevent that people start misusing static methods in interfaces this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference because you can implement multiple interfaces. What if you have an interface C which also has a static method `info()` and you implement both B and C in class A. This would create a problem, that's why it's not allowed.

But when you have two classes A and B, then it's possible because you can only extend one class.

Comment: But that could happen also with default methods: a class can implement two interfaces with a default method with the same signature.